# C++ - How do I insert multiple values into a vector, each with a different index?

Tags: c++, vector, enums

Currently I have a vector holding references to all the rooms connected to a specific room:

```
rooms.at(1).connectedRooms = { &rooms.at(2), &rooms.at(3), &rooms.at(4), &rooms.at(5)};
```

However I would like to use my enum as the index, rather than an integer, so instead of `rooms.at(1).connectedRooms.at(0)` I would use `rooms.at(1).connectedRooms.at(NORTH)` which makes much more sense and also allows it to be used more easily and legibly in switch statements.

The enum looks like

```
enum directions { NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST};
```

Is there a way to do this on one line, for example (this code doesn't work, but it's what I would like to do):

```
rooms.at(1).connectedRooms[NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST] = {&rooms.at(2), &rooms.at(3), &rooms.at(4), &rooms.at(5)};
```

Rather than the much longer

```
rooms.at(1).connectedRooms[NORTH] = &rooms.at(2);
rooms.at(1).connectedRooms[EAST] = &rooms.at(3);
rooms.at(1).connectedRooms[SOUTH] = &rooms.at(4);
rooms.at(1).connectedRooms[WEST] = &rooms.at(5);
```

Thanks

Comment: You could use a loop or write a helper function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign integer values to your enum constants:

```
enum directions { NORTH = 0, EAST = 1, SOUTH = 2, WEST = 3 };
```

and then you keep the assignment as is:

```
rooms.at(1).connectedRooms = { &rooms.at(2), &rooms.at(3), &rooms.at(4), &rooms.at(5)};
```

EDIT: as per the comment below, please be aware that the way you are holding pointers to vector members is VERY dangerous and is not considered good practice. Remember that an std::vector is dynamic, so it may decide to change the location of its memory area anytime it needs to, such as when it grows...

Comment: Please do add a warning to OP that taking the address of a vector element is a very risky thing to do.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree with you on the principle, but that seemed to me far beyond the specific question. But your comment is useful and I think hopefully that the OP will not miss it :). EDIT: ok will add some warning

Comment: Won't that replace the entire vector in `connectedRooms`? What if there are other things in there?

Comment: @NeilKirk yes it will, but from the OP it seemed to me that this is what they wanted, the only thing was to ensure a simple way to write it (one line)...

Comment: @NeilKirk Thought over that myself, while pondering an answer to this question, but I figured if there are only four directions, so OP's options are kind of limited. Two `EAST` rooms is not really an option.

Comment: @user4581301 They could be small rooms ;)

Comment: @Neil yes, but that doesnt seem to be the *design choice* of the OP. It can be seen from the assignments such as `rooms.at(1).connectedRooms[NORTH] = ...`

Comment: @NeilKirk That I agree with, but the vector indexing would have problems.  Could go with vector<vector<room>>, I suppose. Why is there no std::graph, I wonder

Comment: @user4581301 I actually have 10 directions, but for simplicity of the question I omitted most of them. And I'll stop using references, I never considered that vectors being dynamic would change my addresses!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will keep your enums and room values defined in that order, you can try this approach:

```
auto& vec = rooms.at(1).connectedRooms;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    vec[i] = &rooms.at(i + 2);
}
```